# select element and assign character in 2D Matrix python

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, python-3.x, pycharm

i have an integer 2D array and im trying to replace a characters instead of the

integers in that 2D array but the output was confusing for me and i cant find the

wrong Command in the Code

```
(1, [(1, 'A'), (3, 4), (5, 6), (6, 5), (9, 2), (4, 9), (4, 2), (2, 9)])
(3, [(1, 'A'), (3, 'C'), (5, 6), (6, 5), (9, 2), (4, 9), (4, 2), (2, 9)])
(2, [(1, 'A'), (3, 'C'), (5, 6), (6, 5), (9, 2), (4, 9), (4, 2), (2, 'B')])
```

and here is the code

```
  import numpy as np
  x = [ (1,2),(3,4),(5,6),(6,5),(9,2),(4,9),(4,2),(2,9) ]
  list (x)
  #print x
  #x[4] = x[0][1], 'A'
  #print x

  #x =[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
  r=len(x)
  i=0
  j=0
  #print "length",r
  for i in range(0,r):
   for j in range(0,1):
    if x[i][j]==1:
      x[i]=x[i][j],'A'
      print (x[i][j], x)

    if x[i][j] == 2:
       x[i] = x[i][j], 'B'
       print (x[i][j], x)

    if x[i][j] == 3:
      x[i]=x[i][j] , 'C'
      print (x[i][j], x)

print i,j
```

for example the first 2D (1,2) the one should be replaced with "A" ...

the expected result is

replace of of this stream with the equivalent character  for example after this Condition the output is :
x = [ (B,D),(C,D),(E,F),(F,E),(I,B),(D,I),(D,B),(B,I) ]

thanks in advance

Comment: use `print()` to see values in variables ie. `i`, `j`, `x[i]`, `x[i][j]`, etc. - It helps to find problem.

Comment: show (in question) expected result.

Comment: Why import numpy?

Comment: Explain the `x[I] = x[I][j], 'A'` line.  What are you trying to?  What is it actually doing?

Answer (score 2):

In an interactive session:

With a simple `x`, and for the initial iteration loop(s):

```
In [461]: x=[(1,2)]
In [462]: x[0]=x[0][0],'A'
In [463]: x
Out[463]: [(1, 'A')]
```

Notice that the `x[0]` tuple has been replaced by a new tuple, `(x[0][0],'A')`, the first tuple element plus the letter.  Your word description made it sound like you wanted to change it to `('A',2)`, and then to `('A','B')`.

2nd, what's with the `j` iteration?  Do you really want `range(2)`?

```
In [465]: list(range(0,1))
Out[465]: [0]
```

==============

If you have a list of lists, replacing sublist elements is easy:

```
In [468]: x=[[1,2]]
In [469]: i=0
In [470]: for j in range(2):
     ...:     if x[i][j]==1:
     ...:         x[i][j]='A'
     ...:     elif x[i][j]==2:
     ...:         x[i][j]='B'
     ...:         
In [471]: x
Out[471]: [['A', 'B']]
```

Doing something similar with a list of tuples is trickier, because you wan't change elements of a tuple; you have to replace the whole tuple.  In fact, it may be simpler to change the tuple into a list temporarily:

```
In [476]: x=[(1,2)]
In [477]: i=0
In [478]: x1 = list(x[i])
     ...: for j in range(2):
     ...:     if x1[j]==1:
     ...:         x1[j]='A'
     ...:     elif x1[j]==2:
     ...:         x1[j]='B'
     ...: x[i]=tuple(x1)
In [479]: x
Out[479]: [('A', 'B')]
```

==========================

To apply to a list of tuples like:

```
In [622]: x = [ (1,2),(3,4),(5,6),(6,5),(9,2),(4,9),(4,2),(2,9) ]
```

I can wrap my code in a function

```
In [623]: def foo(y):
     ...:     x1 = list(y)
     ...:     for j in range(len(x1)):
     ...:        if x1[j]==1:
     ...:             x1[j]='A'
     ...:        elif x1[j]==2:
     ...:             x1[j]='B'
     ...:     return tuple(x1)
     ...:
```

and apply it to each tuple with a simple list comprehension.  (It could also be coded as an in-place replacement, but the comprehension is prettier.

```
In [624]: [foo(y) for y in x]
Out[624]: [('A', 'B'), (3, 4), (5, 6), (6, 5), (9, 'B'), (4, 9), (4, 'B'), ('B', 9)]
```

I could the other letters to `foo`, or I could simplify it with use of `chr()` and `ord()`:

```
In [625]: def foo1(y):
     ...:     x1 = list(y)
     ...:     for j in range(len(x1)):
     ...:        x1[j] = chr(x1[j]+ord('A')-1)
     ...:     return tuple(x1)
     ...: 
In [626]: [foo1(y) for y in x]
Out[626]: 
[('A', 'B'),
 ('C', 'D'),
 ('E', 'F'),
 ('F', 'E'),
 ('I', 'B'),
 ('D', 'I'),
 ('D', 'B'),
 ('B', 'I')]
```

I could further streamline the function to:

```
def foo2(y):
    return tuple(chr(j+ord('A')-1) for j in y)
```

or even put it all in one comprehension:

```
[tuple(chr(j+ord('A')-1) for j in y) for y in x]
```

Comment: im sorry but your answer was on x[(1,2)] respectively >>> what i want is apply this algorithm on this stream       x = [ (2,4),(3,4),(5,6),(6,5),(9,2),(4,9),(4,2),(2,9) ]

so i need to replace this integers to character depends on the Condition of equality

Comment: But you are working on each tuple individually, right?  I'm just illustrating the task with a shorter list.  Surely you can apply that solution to the individual elements of a longer list.

Comment: Edited the expected output >>>> but when i applied it on the stream of integers it assigned just the first two element 
(1,2) – hpaulj

Comment: Did you iterate on `i`?  For sake of illustration I just used `i=0`, but you'd use `for i in range(...)): ...`.

Comment: i got this error TypeError: 'int' object does not support item assignment


here is the code 

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0om5UtdFzWJajNyTXl2eXIxWTQ/view?usp=sharing